# Why is Chroumium Browser Div width and Window.screen.width is not matching?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my html file, i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>YAMKAY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body >
    <header class="hdr_01"> 
      <div class = "hdr_01_div" id = "hdr_01_div">
        <div id="svg_logo_container"></div>
        <div id="topmenu_container"></div>
      </div>  
    </header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>  
  </body>
</html>
```

in the `loader.js` file, i have:

```
const loadScript = (FILE_URL, async = true, type = "text/javascript") => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const scriptEle = document.createElement("script");
            scriptEle.type = type;
            scriptEle.async = async;
            scriptEle.src =FILE_URL;

            scriptEle.addEventListener("load", (ev) => {
                resolve({ status: true });
            });

            scriptEle.addEventListener("error", (ev) => {
                reject({
                    status: false,
                    message: `Failed to load the script ＄{FILE_URL}`
                });
            });   
            document.body.appendChild(scriptEle);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(proceed, 1);
});

function proceed() {
    loadComponents();
    loadVars();

}

function loadVars() {
    loadScript("variables.js").then( data  => {
        console.log("Script loaded successfully", data);
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}


function loadComponents() {

    loadScript("components_mobile.js").then( data  => {
        console.log("Script loaded successfully", data);
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.error(err);
    });


    loadScript("components_wide.js").then( data  => {
        console.log("Script loaded successfully", data);
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

In `variables.js` :

```
var wfull = window.screen.width;                                                                                //not trimmed to account for scrollbar
var hfull = window.screen.height;   
var monitorType = null;

if ((wfull <=  319) && (   true     )) monitorType = 0;                                                         // Joke?
if ((wfull <=  480) && (wfull >  320)) monitorType = 1;                                                         // Mobile phone
if ((wfull <=  768) && (wfull >  481)) monitorType = 2;                                                         // IPAD / Tablet
if ((wfull <= 1024) && (wfull >  769)) monitorType = 3;                                                         // small laptop
if ((wfull <= 1200) && (wfull > 1025)) monitorType = 4;                                                         // large screen / desktop
if ((  true )       && (wfull > 1201)) monitorType = 5;                                                         // TV

console.log("width is: " + wfull);
console.log("Monitor Type is: " + monitorType);

switch (monitorType) {
    case 1 :
        addMobileHeader(wfull, hfull * 0.1);
        break;
}
```

and finally, in `components_mobile.js` :

```
function addMobileHeader(w,h)  {
    if (h > 80 ) h = 80;        // max height = 30;

    var hd = document.createElement("div");

    hd.style.position       = "absolute";
    hd.style.width          = w + "px";
    hd.style.height         = h + "px";
    hd.style.top                = "0";
    hd.style.left           = "0";
    hd.style.background     = "url('assets/plasma_hdr.jpg')"
    hd.style.borderBottom   = "1px solid red";

    document.body.appendChild(hd);
}
```

I am testing for responsiveness in chromium browser with device selection mode. The `window.screen.width` is returning the correct value.

[image]

Note, the width 360 px is matching.

Now I open object inspector:

[image]

Even though, I have the width 360px in the style, the div only expands about halfway in the screen.

**Question**
Why is this? All help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your HTML does not contain a `viewport` meta tag, which is important especially regarding display on mobile devices. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: You are reinventing media queries.

Comment: @epascarello yes. I find it easier to do it that way

Comment: The solution is already available: CSS. Since you provide none, it's clear that the body's padding is included in the width, but the div gets moved by the padding. Also, reinventing the wheel to make something less usable is quite the self-own. Your code is 100% more likely to have issues than what the browser already provides.

Comment: if you want your div to be full-width why not use `width: 100vw` ?

Comment: does this happen on document ready or it happens when you resize your window?

Comment: ah, please note your second screenshot: the box scheme shows a "position" of 620px from the right (not to mention 1939px from the bottom)

Comment: @GrafiCode that is a good point, i did not see. But now i am confused. and this is happening at window loading